# How to add/update params to href attribute via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have a page which has an anchor element:

```
<a id="courses" href="/courses">Courses</a>
```

And I want to add or update some params to the `href`, for example:

- Add a `country` params: `<a id="courses" href="/courses?country=US">Courses</a>`
- Update the `country` params from `US` to `UK`: `<a id="courses" href="/courses?country=UK">Courses</a>`

What's the best way to do it via JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery `.attr( function )` to add/edit `href` attribute of element. In function check if attribute hasn't `country` parameter, add to it and if has edit it.

```js
$("#courses").attr("href", function(i, href){
  var index = href.indexOf("?");
  return (index == -1 ? href : href.substring(0, index)) + "?country=US";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="courses" href="/courses">Courses</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the hardest part is to update the params.

Comment: @Stephen The code update `country` if it is exist in url. Check http://jsfiddle.net/y02a9j6x/

Comment: Thanks, the idea of your answer is what I want. Actually, I want to keep url params  as well. So `var params = new URLSearchParams(location.search)`. And then `(index == -1 ? href : href.substring(0, index)) + "?" + params`

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function as the second parameter to the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to modify the *href* attribute.

Try the following way:

```js
// set
$("#courses").attr('href','/courses?country=US'); 
console.log($("#courses").attr('href'));

// update
$('#setParam').click(function(){
  $("#courses").attr('href', function(_, el){
    return el.replace(/(country=)[a-z]+/ig, '$1UK');
  });
  console.log($("#courses").attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="courses" href="/courses">Courses</a>
<button id="setParam" type="button">Set Param</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrrite a custom function to handle adding properties to the href attribute.

```js
// function to change href attribute

function addPropertyToCourses(prop,value) { 

   var courses = document.getElementById('courses');
   if (courses.href.indexOf("?") == -1) { 
      courses.href += "?"; 
   } else {
      courses.href += "&";
   }
   courses.href += prop + '=' + value;
}

(function() { 
 // add properties
    addPropertyToCourses("country", "UK");
    addPropertyToCourses("someProp", "someValue");
})();
```

```html
<a id="courses" href="/courses">Courses</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example in both JavaScript, and jQuery.

#### Vanilla JavaScript

```js
function updateCountry (element, country) {
  var url = element.getAttribute('href');

  if (url.includes('country')) {
    url = url.replace(/(\?country=)[A-Z]{2}/, `$1${country}`)
  } else {
    url = url.concat(`?country=${country}`)
  };

  element.setAttribute('href', url);

  console.log(element.getAttribute('href'));
}

var element = document.getElementById('courses');

updateCountry(element, 'US'); // Add
updateCountry(element, 'UK'); // Update
```

```html
<a id="courses" href="/courses">Courses</a>
```

### jQuery

```js
function updateCountry (element, country) {
  var url = element.attr('href');
  
  if (url.includes('country')) {
    url = url.replace(/(\?country=)[A-Z]{2}/, `$1${country}`)
  } else {
    url = url.concat(`?country=${country}`)
  };

  element.attr('href', url);

  console.log(element.attr('href'));
}

var element = $('#courses');

updateCountry(element, 'US'); // Add
updateCountry(element, 'UK'); // Update
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="courses" href="/courses">Courses</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `attr` will add `country` to the element's attribute, not in `href`.

Comment: Apologies, misread your question, I've updated my code appropriately